# Products not appearing in categories (no footer either)

Tags: category, products, footer

I have been trying to get this working for the past two days.

None of my products are appearing in my categories. The category title, description and feature image appear but no products and also no footer (like other pages on the site)

It seems the categories have a missing block for the products to appear and the footer block is missing.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can only answer and not comment this will have to do. 
What theme are you using? Did you edit any core files? Can you tell more please about this? Are the products properly assigned to the categories?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's an error after the description block that's stopping the rest of the page loading, which could be why you have no footer. Can you 'view source code' from that page in your browser and post it here?